# Swapping elements in tuples - football calendar generator

Tags: python, list, tuples

Here is my code:

```
        n = int(len(teams_names) / 2)

    rounds = []
    for i in range(len(teams_names) - 1):
        t = teams_names[:1] + teams_names[-i:] + teams_names[1:-i] if i else teams_names
        rounds.append(list(zip(t[:n], reversed(t[n:]))))
    one_round_length = len(rounds)
    list(rounds)
    for i in range(len(rounds)):
        one_round = rounds[one_round_length-i-1]
        for j in range(len(one_round)):
            one_round[j][0], one_round[j][1] = one_round[j][1], one_round[j][0] 
        rounds.append(one_round)
```

But I have TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment in the line:

```
            one_round[j][0], one_round[j][1] = one_round[j][1], one_round[j][0]
```

The code is to create the football matches calendar. In the first ,,round", creates random pairs of the teams. And in the second "round" I want to reverse host-guest teams pairs.

For example, without reverse I have:

```
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club')]
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club')]
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', Villareal CF')]

[('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', Villareal CF')]
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club')]
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club')]
```

I want to have:

```
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club')]
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club')]
[('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', Villareal CF')]

[('Athletic Club', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Villareal CF', Sevilla FC')]
[('Villareal CF', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Sevilla FC')]
[('Sevilla FC', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Sevilla FC')]
```

Comment: You can't. As the error suggests, tuples are immutable. Use lists instead

Comment: …or create a new tuple: `one_round[j] = one_round[j][1], one_round[j][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the following list

```
rounds = [
('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club'),
('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club'),
('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Villareal CF'),
('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Villareal CF'),
('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club'),
('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club')]
```

apply the following code and print

```
reversed_rounds = [(y,x) for x,y in rounds]
print(reversed_rounds)
```

Output:

```
[('Sevilla FC', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Villareal CF'), 
('Villareal CF', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Sevilla FC'), 
('Athletic Club', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Villareal CF', 'Sevilla FC'), 
('Athletic Club', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Villareal CF', 'Sevilla FC'), 
('Villareal CF', 'Atletico Madrid'), 'Athletic Club', 'Sevilla FC'), 
('Sevilla FC', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Villareal CF')]
```

## OR

try the following one to get exactly what you want

```
rounds = [
    [('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club')],
    [('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club')],
    [('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Villareal CF')],
    [('Atletico Madrid', 'Athletic Club'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Villareal CF')],
    [('Atletico Madrid', 'Villareal CF'), ('Sevilla FC', 'Athletic Club')],
    [('Atletico Madrid', 'Sevilla FC'), ('Villareal CF', 'Athletic Club')]
]

final_list = []
for li in rounds:
    inner_list=[]
    for tup in li:
        x,y = tup
        inner_list.append((y,x))
    final_list.append(inner_list)

for item in final_list:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
[('Sevilla FC', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Villareal CF')]
[('Villareal CF', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Sevilla FC')]
[('Athletic Club', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Villareal CF', 'Sevilla FC')]
[('Athletic Club', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Villareal CF', 'Sevilla FC')]
[('Villareal CF', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Sevilla FC')]
[('Sevilla FC', 'Atletico Madrid'), ('Athletic Club', 'Villareal CF')]
```

Comment: The code looks right but your sample output doesn't.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. please check again.